# Unable to create a customer as an ordinary user when applying a Record rule in openerp7

Tags: odoo

**I've the below requirement**

- Ordinary user must be able to see all customers
- Ordinary user must see only contacts created by themselves
- Ordinary user must be able to create a new customer
- Ordinary user must be able to create a new contact (under a customer)

**I've the below domain filter**

```
['|','|',('created_user','=',user.id),('created_user','=',False),('customer','=',True)]
```

**My Record Rule is**

[image]

**My Problem is**

I am unable to create a customer, contact as an ordinary user. But able to do the same as admin.

**Error message i see is**

```
Access Denied

The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Partner, Operation: read)
```

I would like to know wt really happens when we apply a record rule with a domain filter. I've given full permission for partner object. But it says read permission doesn't exist. By disabling this record rule i am able to create a customer, contact as an ordinary user.  Kindly suggest. Thanks for your time. :)